# Why is query selector clicking the div but no actions is triggered?

Tags: javascript, dom, button, css-selectors, click

I've been trying to use the JavaScript `click()` function to click the follow button on this [page](https://shopee.com.my/shop/143551842/followers?__classic__=1)

When I click it manually with the mouse, the button changes color from orange to white, and follows the user.

- This is the page before clicking the Follow button manually:
  [Before manual click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zbai.png)
- And this is the picture after clicking the Follow button manually:
  [After manual click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFCGI.png)

However, when I use the following JavaScript code to click the button:

```
    document.querySelector('#shop-followers > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div.btn-follow.follow.L14').click()
```

It triggers a click, but the color of the button does not change from orange to white, and it does not follow the user as well.

I've tried many times but it just isn't working for me. Not sure if there's something different with this site that causes the `click()` function to not work. Does anyone have a workaround for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are aspects of human interaction with the web that can't be duplicated in script. The authors of the script may be inspecting the `Event` object looking for the `isTrusted` flag before changing the class as a way of deterring people from faking sales and the like.

Comment: Try .trigger('click') insted ok .click()

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dispatchEvent` instead. The `dispatchEvent` method will dispatch an event at the specified target. You can also allow the event to bubble up the DOM, where other logic may be occurring.

Example:

```
document.querySelector(".btn-follow").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: 0,
    clientY: 0,
    button: 0
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I tried your code and it still doesn't work. Same outcome as with the click() function.

Comment: @CreativeCommonsStudio Hmm, it seemed to work for me when I tried it. But the main thing that's occurring on their site is a CSS class (`active`) is added to the `div` element after it's clicked. If you add the `active` class to the `div` manually in dev tools, you should see it change to white. But I'm not sure where in their code this is occurring after the event fires. And unfortunately, since it can't be tested without registering for an account on that site, it might be difficult to get answers from the community.

Comment: This is a good answer. The most likely reason it is not working for you is because the selector is not specific enough on your browser. Try this bit of code: `document.querySelector('#shop-followers > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div.btn-follow.follow.L14 .L14').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {bubbles: true}))` the most important part of the `dispatchEvent` method is that it allows for bubbling options on the event. This means you can select the most focused element, the span inside the button with text, and click that.